# Bootstrap navigation does not work with new bootstrap.min.css but works with an earlier version

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am creating a menu using bootstrap. The menu collapses to a hamburger menu when toggleable. 
The navigation works with an earlier version of bootstap.min.css but does not work with the most recent downloaded bootstrap 4.0. In the code below /vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap4.0beta/js/bootstrap.min.js and /vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap4.0beta/css/bootstrap.css are new versions.  vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css and vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js are earlier ones. Here only the older version of css works (with both older and new versions of js). Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

         <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"> <!--> Older version of bootstrap css  -->
     <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap4.0beta/css/bootstrap.css"> -->
    <title>Salapaka Lab</title>
  </head>
<body>

        <nav class="navbar  fixed-top  navbar-inverse  navbar-toggleable-sm" style="background-color: black;">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myMenu" aria-controls="myMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                </span>
            </button>  
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Salapaka Lab</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myMenu" >
              <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a  class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">People</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Publications</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Downloads</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </div><!-- navbar-nav -->
            </div> <!--collapse -->
        </nav><!-- nav -->




        <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap4.0beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "not work" means exactly? Could you please elaborate on that? Thanks!

Comment: Here is what happens: The brand appears on a black background; none of the nav-items, Home, People,Publications, Downloads or Contact appear. The hamburger menu does not appear when the viewport is made small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 `.navbar`s need an additional class of `.navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}` (e.g.: `.navbar-expand-sm`). Bootstrap docs mention this at the top of the [Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#how-it-works) description.

In this specific case, I think you can freely rename the current `.navbar-toggleable-sm` class to `.navbar-expand-sm` and it should work fine.